# Converting JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I've found two different answers to this question - [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722156/1525840) applying *JsonConvert* (including *JObject*, *JArray*, *JToken*) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8291696/1525840) working with *JavaScriptSerializer*. Both are getting a bit dated (especially the latter) and since I just learned that e.g. *WebClient* (which was suggested by many) is outdated by *HttpClient*, I'm not sure which to use (or if there's an even newer and preferred way.

I don't get any hints on these with my intellisense, neither, so I'm suspecting that they're not so widely appropriate.

I have a string that contains JSON formatted data. How does one get it into something workable in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, the short answer is Json.NET, with code samples here:

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

```
var json = "{email:'bob@gmail.com'}";
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not fully sure. In your example it seems like I need to know the type of the object (*User*). Perhaps it's not such a big problem. However, something that is a problem is that it's half past one in the morning in Sweden and my brains is flipping me a bird - where/how do I download the assemblies for the library that you suggested? There's no "download" there. Or am I just too tired?! I've tried with "json" and "newtonsoft" in VS's manager...

Comment: @KonradViltersten The same way you obtain most popular libraries, via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). And yes, with the `DeserializeObject()` method you need to have a type definition ahead of time. But Json.NET has support for situations even when you don't. Just look through their documentation.

Comment: @mason I get nada hits when I try to manage the packages after right-mousing the references menu... It's supposed to look filled, like [this](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)... Maybe I'm just too stupid to use internet today, hehe. Or too tired...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Read the directions. Also if you're tired. Just go to bed. It can wait until morning. You'll avoid asking dumb questions that you'd probably be able to easily find the answer to when you're well rested.

Comment: @mason No argue there. Too stubborn for my own good. Gonna hug the pillows now...

Comment: Yep, get some sleep. And in the morning get nuget console and go like `Install-Package Json.Net`. And it should be like `man, here you go, totally installing the package for you`. And you should go like `maaaannn, that was silly, I should really listen to strangers online, when they tell me to go to bed` -)

Comment: @trailmax Hehe, it's *Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json*, apparently, as shown [on the Internet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Still, I was expecting it to show in my gallery or something (plus I spelled "Json" with a "q", yesterday - no idea how).

Comment: @KonradViltersten duh to myself! I'm so not used to install Json.Net myself - I don't know the package name.All my other dependencies depend on it - it is installed automatically for me. Probably I should also get more sleep -)